# Magento2 Radio.js file

Tags: magento2

Can anyone help me to add radio.js file for adding radio button validation for custom options in magento2 ?

Please find the below screen shot:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

From the Screenshot am assuming you are trying to add a new JS to adminhtml.

For this you need to create a basic module. Inside the module view folder create "adminhtml/layout" folder and place the default.xml folder. This default.xml file will load css or js on all the adminhtml pages.

If you want to load on specific pages for Eg: while creating new category. you need to use its corresponding layout file catalog_category_add.xml and in head section you call your JS or css file.

You can find more info here https://mage2.pro/t/topic/34

Clear the cache and run static-content:deploy command after adding new JS

Comment: Thanks for the response, can you send me the radio.js file